# Format Date using Javascript Object Model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, date-time

I am using the javascript object model to get a date field back and display it on a page e.g. oListItem.get_item("MyTestDate")

This displays on the page by default as: Thu Jul 25 09:30:07 PDT 2013

I want to display it as: 25 Jul 2013, 09:30

How do i format a date when using the JSOM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ASP.NET AJAX (which is a part of SharePoint - MicrosoftAjax.js) extends the JavaScript Date object with a formatting function that closely mimics the [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method

So, in your case the format string should be as follows: `dd MMM yyyy, hh:ss`

```
var modified = item.get_item("Modified");
var fmtModified = modified.format('dd MMM yyyy, hh:ss');
```

For a full list of formatting string parameters, see the [Standard DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [Custom DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) reference pages on MSDN

Comment: Your suggestion does not work in javascript object model on IE 8.

Comment: It works on my computer, but what about specifying the culture?

Comment: Vadim, extremely helphul! I've sp[ent few hours oO getRelativeDateTimeString didn't work for me, it does not include time.. You saved my time! Thank You much!

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

It is easy to learn and very small.

Comment: I was about to suggest this myself. Moment.js is an excellent library. I use it in all of my SharePoint projects that have custom front-end work.

Comment: [Moment.js is deprecated](https://momentjs.com/docs/)